# Using a Boot Camp partition as a Virtualbox disk

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I've got a Mac with a Windows 8 Boot Camp partition set up.

How can I create and configure a Virtualbox disk that is that Boot Camp partition?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this article](http://c-notes.net/2014/11/converting-a-bootcamp-partition-to-a-virtual-disk-vdi-virtualbox/):

- Unmount/Eject your Boot camp partition
- Create a raw VMDK image that will mirror the existing partition layout (change the device and partition as necessary *)
- Create a VDI image that will copy the data from the partitions selected in the previous step